# data.table: create multiple columns with lapply and .SD

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to apply the `scale()` function over multiple columns of a `data.table` to define new columns. I am getting the following error:

```
dt = data.table( id = rep( 1:10, each = 10 ), 
             A = rnorm( 100, 1, 2 ), 
             B = runif( 100, 0, 1 ),
             C = rnorm( 100, 10, 20 ) )


cols_to_use    = c( "A", "B", "C" )
cols_to_define = paste0( cols_to_use, "_std" )

# working
dt[ , ( cols_to_define ) := lapply( .SD, scale ), .SDcols = cols_to_use ]

# not working
dt[ , ( cols_to_define ) := lapply( .SD, scale ), by = id, .SDcols = cols_to_use ]
## Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`((cols_to_define), lapply(.SD, scale)),  : 
## All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. 
## If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then
## use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.
```

Any ideas why when removing the `by` operation this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is the with output of `scale` which is a `matrix`

```
dim(scale(dt$A))
#[1] 100   1
```

so, we need to change it to a `vector` by removing the `dim` attributes.  Either `as.vector` or `c` would do it

```
dt[ , ( cols_to_define ) := lapply( .SD, function(x) 
          c(scale(x)) ), by = id, .SDcols = cols_to_use ]
```

---

When there is no `by` the `matrix` `dim` attributes gets dropped while keeping the other attributes.

Comment: When I use the vector with column names cols_to_use= c( "A", "B", "C" ), the result is a set of new columns with the original names plus the suffix "_std", (i.e "A_std"). However, if the scaled columns are subset using grep cols_to_use=grep("^A|^B|^C", names(DT)) the new columns are named with the column position plus the suffix (i.e "16_std", "17_std", "18:_std"). How can I keep the original column name as prefix, when using grep?